# How should I store a password to allow people to enter single characters from it?

Tags: hash, password-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do some sites (e.g. online banks) only ask for specific characters from a password without storing it as plaintext?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4830/how-do-some-sites-e-g-online-banks-only-ask-for-specific-characters-from-a-pa)

Some banking applications ask for random letters from your password, the 3<sup>rd</sup>, 5<sup>th</sup> and 6<sup>th</sup> letters for example.

Presumably this is to limit the effectiveness of sniffing the network traffic or keylogging to get password information.

I was wondering how this information is likely stored so that they are able to see individual characters in the password but presumably have them stored in a secure way?

Would each character get salted and hashed? If so would each get stored in different columns of a table? Or would each three letter permutation of the password characters get stored in a table unique to the user?

Comment: Interesting system. I have never seen one like it. I highly doubt the effectiveness of it though.

Comment: I can't think of anyway this could be done that would be even remotely secure.

Comment: Such data is most likely encrypted, not hashed. My bank requires me to provide a valid client certificate, password and once I want to perform a transaction it wants me to give 2 letters (chosen by bank at random for each transaction) from a second "password", which is used solely for this purpose.

Comment: They use a [HSM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module), such that the requests go into the device (are character 4, 6 and 7 of 4395092's secret word 'b', 'e' and 's'?) and it spits out a yes / no answer. The HSM is usually configured to prevent extraction of any full ciphertexts or keys.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, but I don't think a hash is practical here. Sure you can make a hash of one letter, but it's incredibly easy to brute-force if it ever leaks (like, a few microseconds at most); under 100 possibilities. Also storing all 3-char permutations hashed would be too easy to reverse.

It's actually interesting to consider this system from this angle. Usually you're calculating how many login attempts you would need in a worst- and best-case before an attacker knows the full password (or is able to login within 3 attempts), or how much security this system adds anyway (with MITM an attacker can still login). I never thought about what it meant for storing the login, and it's not looking good.