# How can IA-5(1)(b) be enforced on non-Windows systems?

Tags: compliance, password-management, nist

I have a question posted already for [this issue in Windows systems](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3169/how-can-ia-51b-be-enforced-on-windows-systems), and thought that non-Windows systems should perhaps be covered separately.

In NIST SP 800-53 Rev. 3, IA-5 is the control addressing "Authenticator Management". The requirements in this control include such things as enforcement of password length, complexity, lifetime, history, and proper storage/transmission of passwords.

The first enhancement for this control, which is selected for all (Low/Moderate/High) systems includes this requirement:

> The information system, for password-based authentication:
>
> ...
>
> (b) Enforces at least a [Assignment: organization-defined number of changed characters] when new passwords are created;

In most systems, it's pretty easy to find and configure the rules that enforce long and complex passwords which are changed regularly and do not exactly match a certain number of old passwords.  But, how do you implement a policy that requires a certain amount of characters to be changed with every new password?

Some systems I'm interested in (feel free to address others):

- Mac OS X
- Linux/Unix (Any/all flavors)
- Cisco IOS

Comment: For Cisco IOS, simply set [`char-changes 8`](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/sec_usr_aaa/configuration/xe-16-12/sec-usr-aaa-xe-16-12-book/sec-aaa-comm-criteria-pwd.html) (or whatever your value is) to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I would recommend for enterprises would be to integrate these systems with your directory service, which for most will be Active Directory. This way your password policy is set in a single place and it bring other benefits in managing access control and roles in a single place. You can also then provide single sign-on and two factor authentication.

Guidance on doing this:

- MAC:
  http://www.seminars.apple.com/contactme/pdf/L334436B_ActiveDirect_WP.pdf
- Linux Ubuntu:
  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ActiveDirectoryHowto

For Cisco IOS however TACACS+ or Radias servers are the best place to set policy centrally.

Comment: So, you're saying integrate all non-Windows systems with AD as much as you can and then solve the issue on Windows?

Comment: Yes that would be the best strategic option IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy to do with PAM, so that covers Linux/Solaris/FreeBSD at least. Among other things the [`pam_cracklib`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_cracklib) module offers that functionality. Its default setting is actually to check for five character changed but can be configured by the `difok` option.